# "had a test in English today" vs. "had an English test today"

Tags: sentence-usage

Is it ok to say:

> "I had a test in English today"

Or should I say:

> "I had an English test today"

instead?

I think I actually have seen it expressed like "in English" but I just read it wasn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

"A test in English" is ambiguous - it could mean a test in any subject which is conducted in English (as opposed to some other language) or a test whose subject is English. An English test simply means a test whose subject is English.

Comment: The potential ambiguity (such as it is) would only normally apply to learners. For native Anglophones, *all* tests would normally be conducted using the English language, so the only reason for saying ***in English*** would be to identify the *subject* of the test.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You make a strong point there.

Comment: Not all tests. At my school in London, lessons and tests could be conducted in Latin, German, and French as well as (mostly) English.

Comment: I think there's still further potential for confusion. When I was at school we could have a test in English, or a test in Biology, or Physics - you were naming the 'class' not the language.

Comment: My answer addresses that source of confusion (ambiguity) - a test conducted in English vs. a test whose subject (class, topic) is English.

Comment: Also it is non-standard to capitalise the names of school subjects.